# Como convertir una lista añadida desde consola como float

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import det, inv, matrix_power

x_d = input("Ingrese los valores del array x: ").split(' ')

lim = len(x_d)
lista = []

for i in range(0, lim):
    lista.append(float(x_d[i].split(',')))
print(lista)
```

Como podria convertir estos datos en  flotantes? para poder operar varias matrices entre ellas, usando linalg de numpy. Que si los tengo en string no me deja. Gracias

Comment: hay otro post con lo mismo, en una línea: xd=np.array([[float(z) for z in x.split()] for x in input("Ingrese las filas separados por ; y las columnas por espacios: ").split(";")])

Comment: @tincopasan es el mismo usuario, pero la pregunta es distinta, la anterior ya fue respondida

Comment: @AnkiJedi con más razón es más de lo mismo, simple comprensión de listas. además que editó la pregunta totalmente.

Comment: Muchas gracias. @tincopasan, si lo publicas como una respuesta con gusto te doy el upvote

Comment: quieres recibir una matriz multidiensional y convertirla con np?

Answer (score 1):

Para trabajar con matrices(se les dice así si son bidimensionales) se busca un formato:

```
matriz=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

en el caso de:

```
vector=[1,2,3]
```

es una matriz unidimensional, más conocida como vector

entonces si queremos una matriz ingresada por un input, deberíamos generar una lista de listas, ya usas split(), sin nada como parámetro usa por default el separador espacio.
No voy a explicar la compresión de lista porque básicamente lo hicieron en otro post similar.
entonces:

```
import numpy as np

xd=np.array([[float(z) for z in x.split()] for x in input("Ingrese las filas separados por ; y las columnas por espacios: ").split(";")]) 

print(xd)
```

donde usando array de numpy y compresión de listas tenemos una matriz de numpy

si ingreso:

1 2;3 4

se obtiene:

```
[[1. 2.]
 [3. 4.]]
```

que es un array de numpy

como comentario devuelve en este caso valores decimales, podrían se cualquiera que sea admitido por numpy y el ingreso permite cualquier dimensión de matriz siendo espacio el separador de columnas y ; el de filas

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que entiendo lo que quieres es hacer una matriz `n*m` y que los datos sean ingresados desde la consola, lo podemos hacer combinando un ciclo `for` con mi respuesta anterior.

Primero vamos a pedirle al usuario que ingrese el numero de listas que contendrá la matriz, lo que representaría el valor `n` en la matriz de dimensiones `n*m` y luego solo pedimos los datos de cada lista y convertimos esos valores a `float`

```py
import numpy as np


dimension = int(input("ingrese el numero de listas que tendra la matriz: "))

matriz = []#aqui se almacenara los valores

for i in range(dimension):#iteramos segun el numero de listas que dijo
    #acemos el proceso de conversion de datos
    lista = input(f"Ingrese los valores de la lista #{i}: ").split(',')
    lista = np.array([float(x) for x in lista])
    matriz.append(lista)

#convertimos a tipo numpy
matriz = np.array(matriz)
```

**Probamos**

```
Ingrese los valores de la lista #0: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
Ingrese los valores de la lista #1: 0,0.8,0.9,0.1,-0.6,-0.8,-1,-0.9,-0.4
Ingrese los valores de la lista #2: 0,0.8,0.9,0.1,-0.6,-0.8,-1,-0.9,-0.4

array([[ 0. ,  1. ,  2. ,  3. ,  4. ,  5. ,  6. ,  7. ,  8. ],
       [ 0. ,  0.8,  0.9,  0.1, -0.6, -0.8, -1. , -0.9, -0.4],
       [ 0. ,  0.8,  0.9,  0.1, -0.6, -0.8, -1. , -0.9, -0.4]])
```

Creo que es a esto a lo que te refieres, si no dímelo y hare lo posible para ayudarte :).

Answer (score 0):

En `x_d` estas guardando una lista de `string` donde donde cada uno podría ser convertido a un `float`, digamos por ejemplo `x_d = ['3.4', '23.4']`, luego estas intentando iterar según el tamaño de `x_d` con la función `range()`, hasta acá todo bien, pero en esta linea:

```
lista.append(float(x_d[i].split(',')))
```

Estas tratando de crear una lista con `split()` y luego convertirla a float con `float()`, lo cual no es posible, una solución usando tu código es simplemente eliminar el .split(',') y todo funcionara como debe, aquí te dejo una versión de tu código con pocos cambios:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import det, inv, matrix_power

x_d = input("Ingrese los valores del array x: ").split(' ')
print(x_d)
#lim = len(x_d)  <- ya no hace falta para la iteración
lista = []

for num in x_d:
  lista.append(float(num))
  
print(lista)
```

Prueba:

```
Ingrese los valores del array x: 3.4 22.4 11
[3.4, 22.4, 11.0]
```

*Nota: sé que habrán muchos que no consideraran este pequeño cambio como una respuesta pero creo que la explicación lo amerita xP*

Comment: si bien tu respuesta es funcional la pregunta de ahora es ambigua, quiere trabajar con matrices, eso es más que nada un vector.

Comment: Estoy respondiendo a la pregunta "Como podria convertir estos datos en flotantes?" lo cual si pruebas el codigo dado, da un error por intentar convertir a float una lista, lo que viene despues -->"para poder operar varias matrices entre ellas, usando linalg de numpy." es el objetivo que busca lograr con la lista de floats que anteriormente estaban en string.

Comment: repito: tu respuesta está bien, lo inconcluso es la pregunta.

Comment: ah, me disculpo jajaja, pues sí, estoy suponiendo que luego convertirá la lista a un array con asarray o algún método y que el código que nos esta presentando fue una simplificación de lo que realmente busca hacer

Comment: @AnkiJedi Igualmente muchas gracias por responder la pregunta.

Comment: prácticamente es lo que hice en mi respuesta anterior :/

Comment: jajaja y el man te la puso como correcta no?

Comment: si, pero esta bien por que es lo que el quería. Publique mi respuesta, creo que es eso a lo que se refiere :/